# print member of struct of a vector

Tags: c++, boost

I try to print only a struct member from vector of my struct (struct pnt). let me be clear by showing this:

```
struct pnt {
  char _name;
  int _type;
  bool _aux;
  };

boost::copy(pntVec.begin(),pntVec.end()|
boost::adaptors::transformed(bind(&pnt::_type, _1)), 
std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, "\n"));
```

but I get an error. I will appreciate if you could please help me to find the reason for that.

**Error**:

```
 error: no type named ‘type’ in ‘boost::mpl::eval_if_c<true, boost::range_const_iterator<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int> >, void>, boost::range_mutable_iterator<const __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int> >, void> >::f_ {aka struct boost::range_const_iterator<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int> >, void>}’
```

**NOTE**: I can olny use **C++98, boost v.1.56**

Comment: _"I get an error"_. Please include the exact error message you're getting in your question.

Comment: error has been added

Comment: @H'H did you mean `boost::copy(pntVec | boost::adaptors::transformed(bind(&pnt::_type, _1)), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, "\n"));` ?

Comment: @PiotrS. yes, I want to print the integer part of all vector member

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz `std::basic_ostream` does not have `push_back` member function, no reason for `back_inserter`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Boost *Adaptor* adapts *ranges*, not single *iterators*. Similarily, the `boost::copy` algorithm expects two arguments, where the first one is a *range*, and the second an *output iterator*. Having said that, the correct syntax for extracting a single data member from a *range*, and copying it to an output iterator is:

```
boost::copy(pntVec | boost::adaptors::transformed(bind(&pnt::_type, _1))
          , std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, "\n"));
```

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, since Phoenix in a way supersedes Boost Bind + Boost Lambda, you could use Boost Phoenix:

```
boost::for_each(pntVec, std::cout << bind(&pnt::_type, arg1) << "\n");
```

or even without `bind`, if you don't fear a bit of arcane syntax:

```
boost::for_each(v, std::cout << (arg1->*&pnt::_type) << "\n");
```

That's pretty expressive. See it **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bc18be17db371a70)**

---

Also, note that there's `mem_fn` in Boost/c++11: `pntVec | transformed(mem_fn(&pnt::_type))`

Comment: Added the [member pointer operator](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/phoenix/doc/html/phoenix/modules/operator.html#phoenix.modules.operator.member_pointer_operator) syntax variant for completeness